# iOS Going Back To View on Different NavigationController

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, segue

So i have my storyboard laid out like this the below image.

I want to start in the first tab view i.e. where I've written "START IN THIS VIEW". From that page, on clicking a cell in the table pushes the next view onto self.navigationController (view directly below) from which a user would follow to the screen that says "DONE".

On pressing the done button I want to move back to the "GO BACK HERE" screen however on popToRootViewController it keeps ending up on the first view of the middle navigation controller. How do i get back to the view controller on the first tab?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By popping to the root view controller from the DONE view controller, it will, as you said, take you to the first view controller in your middle navigation controller since that is the hierarchy visible at the moment.

What you want to do is select the `UITabBarController` `selectedIndex` from within your view controller, like so:

```
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0;
```

The above will select the first tab.

**Edit:**

Assuming you have a reference to formPage1 from the START FROM THIS VIEW controller:

```
// set formPage1's properties, then

// Get the middle tab's navigation controller
UINavigationController *navigationControllerAtTabIndex1 = [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];
// Push formPage1 view controller on the middle tab's navigation controller stack
[navigationControllerAtTabIndex1 pushViewController:formPage1 animated:YES];
// Set the selected view controller to the middle tab's navigation controller
self.tabBarController.selectedViewController = [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks but whats odd is the tab gets selected i.e. its highlighted however the view thats displayed is from the middle tab. If i press the Back button in the top left corner it then goes to the correct view.

Comment: @userMod2 - sounds like the DONE controller is being pushed onto the stack of the top row's navigation controller, and is also in the middle row's navigation controller's stack - not good. I suggest coding it so the second tab's index (1) being selected, and pushing the DONE view controller on middle row's navigation controller.

Comment: I think i see what you're saying but then how do i do: [self.navigationController pushViewController:formPage1 animated:YES]; and self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1; I need to do that push as i set some variables on the formPage1 viewController